# Center multiple divs inside a nav

Tags: html, css, nav

I was creating my own site and I wanted to have this navigation menu on top,
which contain 4 divs with each another link to another place on the website, but I cant figure out to get them in the center of the website.

Here's my code;

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="indexc.css">
<title>
Title
</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="balk">
<nav><b>
<div id="b1"><a href="html/" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"><h2>About</h2></a></div>
<div id="b2"><a href="html/" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"><h2>Videos</h2></a></div>
<div id="b3"><a href="html/" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"><h2>History</h2></a></div>
<div id="b4"><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">     <h2>Home</h2></a></div>
</b></nav>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the stylesheet;

```
body {font-family:sans-serif;background-image: url("pictures/rain.jpg");}
#b1 {border-style:solid;border-color:#7f7f7f;width:310px;text-align:center;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:3px;background-color:#7f7f7f;opacity:0.8;position:fixed;}
#b2 {border-style:solid;border-color:#7f7f7f;width:310px;text-align:center;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:3px;background-color:#7f7f7f;opacity:0.8;position:fixed;left:323px;}
#b3 {border-style:solid;border-color:#7f7f7f;width:310px;text-align:center;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:3px;background-color:#7f7f7f;opacity:0.8;position:fixed;left:637.5px;}
#b4 {border-style:solid;border-color:#7f7f7f;width:310px;text-align:center;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:3px;background-color:#7f7f7f;opacity:0.8;position:fixed;left:952px;}
```

Now the navigation menu is on the left but I want it to be in the exact middle of the page, no matter what the size is of the screen.

Anyway, thanks if you can help me out!

Comment: Why not use list items

Comment: I have made edit to my answer... let me know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

There were really many things, which have to be done... I used smaller width for `nav div`, from yours 310px to 150px, to see it on JSFiddle. You can change it bake to 310px. Also then just change width for `nav` from 650px to atleast 4x width of yours `nav div`, to have all 4 menu items in one row. All your 4 divs are in a row because of `float: left;` and then also `nav` needs to have `clear: both;`.

I also suggest you to use list items (`<ul><li>...</li><li>...</li>...</ul>`).

**HTML:**

```
<p id="balk">
    <nav>
        <div id="b1"><a href="html/"><h2>About</h2></a></div>
        <div id="b2"><a href="html/"><h2>Videos</h2></a></div>
        <div id="b3"><a href="html/"><h2>History</h2></a></div>
        <div id="b4"><a href="index.html"><h2>Home</h2></a></div>
    </nav>
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background-image: url("pictures/rain.jpg");
}

nav {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav:after {
    clear: both;
}

nav div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#7f7f7f;
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    background-color:#7f7f7f;
    opacity:0.8;
    float:left;
}

nav div>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

[See DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/2bk18s9p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

## Disclaimer

I know both of these suggestions have already been made. However, they are either incomplete or, in the case of the text-align method, misleading. I would have preferred to comment on the answers themselves, but I don't currently have enough reputation.

## margin: auto

As @Legionar says, you could apply a margin: auto to your inner navigation elements. However, this requires that a fixed width be applied to your divs (#b1, #b2 etc). If this isn't an option;

## text-align: center

You could also, as @Rajesh says, use text-align center on your parent container (in this case, the *nav* element). However, what he doesn't mention is that you also have to set display: inline-block on your divs for that to work - I'd also advise using clear: both to ensure that they don't appear to float left;

```
nav{
  text-align: center;
}

#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4{
 display: inline-block;
 clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use div within paragraph tags, as they are for text/content.
You also need a wrapper div or a container, which will hold your website body.
e.g

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="indexc.css">
<title>
Title
</title>
<style>
.container{ width:900px; margin:auto; float:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<nav>
<div id="b1"><a href="html/" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"><h2>About</h2></a></div>
<div id="b2"><a href="html/" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"><h2>Videos</h2></a></div>
<div id="b3"><a href="html/" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"><h2>History</h2></a></div>
<div id="b4"><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">     <h2>Home</h2></a></div>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use text-align in that case

```
<nav style="text-align:center;"><b>
  //All div here
</b></nav>
```

In your stylesheet you can do like this, instead of giving everytime in Anchor tag

```
a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
}

#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4
{
 text-align:center;
}
```

It will apply this style to all anchor tag and div tag with following id's